# Black streaming video when casting or connecting with cable to TV

Tags: video

Very confusing problem:

I can watch the live streaming on this website (https://www.la7.it/dirette-tv) on my MacBook Pro.

However, if I connect the computer to my LG OLED TV, the video window goes completely black (both on the laptop screen and the TV screen), see screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of black screen]

This happens both on Safari and Chrome, and only for the live streaming video in that website (non-live videos on the same website work perfectly, and live videos from other sources as youtube also work fine).

This started to happen only recently, while it was working a few months back with same laptop and same TV.

Additionally, I can connect a Windows laptop to the TV and see the live streaming without any problem.

Does anyone have any idea of what's going on, and how to solve the problem? I am very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to overcome the problem by turning off hardware acceleration in Google Chrome.